# Product rule in formal terms

Tags: derivatives, products

I'm given that $R(y)=p(y) * y$
where $p(y)$ and $R(y)$ are functions of $y$

In the question: I need the product rule to find the derivative of $p(y) \cdot y$

I know that the product rule is $\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)\cdot g(x)) = f'(x)g(x) + g'(x)f(x)$.

Would this then give me $p*y + p(y) * 0$?

Comment: You should end up with $p'(y)y+p(y)$...

Comment: The derivative of $y \mapsto y$ is $y \mapsto 1$ not $y \mapsto 0$.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\frac{d}{dy}(p(y)\cdot y) = p(y) \frac{d}{dy}(y) + y\frac{d}{dy}(p(x)) \\
\implies \frac{d}{dy}(p(y)\cdot y) = p(y) + y\cdot p'(y).
$$

Two things you've mistaken:

$(1)$ The derivative of $y$ with respect to $y$ is $1$ and not $0$. If you define $f(y) = y$, then it is immediately obvious from the definition of a derivative:

$$
\frac{d}{dy}(f(y)) = \lim_{\delta y \to 0} \frac{f(y+\delta y) - f(y)}{\delta y} = \lim_{\delta y\to 0} \frac{y+\delta y-y}{\delta y} = 1.
$$

$(2)$ The derivative of $p(y)$ would be denoted by $p'$ and not $p$.